# Android iframe bug

Tags: android, iframe

I have an issue on my phone running Android 4.0.4.

I have an iframe with a text field and a couple of dropdowns, but the iframe is too wide to fit in the phone window when in portrait mode, so I get a horizontal scroll bar so I can scroll to see all of the fields.

The problem is, if I scroll the iframe to the right I can no longer select the text box or the dropdowns.

It looks like the device doesn't realise the iframe has been scrolled to the right, so for example, when the iframe first renders, the content is positioned left aligned. At this moment, one of the dropdowns is visible at the far right of the iframe. If I scroll the iframe all the way to the right and tap the screen where the dropdown ***used*** to be, I get the selection screen for the drop down even though the area of the screen I actually clicked had no element on it at all.

If I tap the screen where the dropdown actually is, I get no response at all.

I have a test page here:
http://snow.x10.mx/damian/page.html

Everything works fine on Firefox on the desktop, so it looks like it may be just an Android bug.

Can anybody suggest a workaround for it (other than making sure the iframe isn't wider than the screen) because I can't see an Android fix coming any time soon!

If anyone has an iPhone they can test it with, can you let me know if you have the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same issue with Android 4.0.4

The same thing happens with vertical scrolling, and applies to input fields, links... Anything that should react to a touch/click event. If the element is visible before scrolling the position where it was is still reacting to the touch event after scrolling. And if it's not visible before scrolling there is nothing you can do to interact with that element.

I'm not sure what's causing this, but using a scrollbar plugin ( [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/index.html) ) has solved it for me.

Good luck!

Comment: Were you ever able to determine what the issue was? I'm running into this problem and haven't been able to find anything helpful.